# Value is continuously increasing when the condition is true. Mediapipe library

Tags: android, mediapipe

When the condition is true my counter value is increasing continuously instead of only one value. If angle is greater than 90 degree it keeps increasing like 1,2,3,4,5 instead of 1 than 2 than 3
Shoulder = new float[] {landmarks.getLandmark(12).getX(),landmarks.getLandmark(12).getY()};
elbow =new float[] {landmarks.getLandmark(24).getX(),landmarks.getLandmark(24).getY()};
wrist = new float[] {landmarks.getLandmark(15).getX(),landmarks.getLandmark(15).getY()};
double angle = calculate_angle(Shoulder, elbow, wrist);
System.out.println(angle);

```
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                String stage="down";

                                // Stuff that updates the UI
                                if (angle > 90) {
                                    stage = "down";
                                    tv.setText(stage);

                                }
                                if (angle <=90 ){
                                    stage = "up";
                                    tv.setText(stage);
                                    doSomething();

                                    System.out.println("This is"+counter);

                                }







                            }
                        });

                        // Note: If eye_presence is false, these landmarks are useless.
                        Log.v(
                                TAG,
                                "[TS:"
                                        + packet.getTimestamp()
                                        + "] #Landmarks for iris: "
                                        + landmarks.getLandmarkCount());
                        Log.v(TAG, getLandmarksDebugString(landmarks));
                    } catch (InvalidProtocolBufferException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't Exception received - " + e);
                        return;
                    }
                });
//        }
    }
    public int doSomething(){
        counter = counter +1;
        tv2.setText(String.valueOf(counter));

        System.out.println("This is bingo"+counter);
        return (counter);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to add some delay. You'll need to either tamper with the UI thread ie Thread.sleeep()  or use System.currentTimeMillis() to check the last time the thread ran it's work.